# creating functional index with a order by clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, indexing

I Need to create a order by index on a table

```
Student (
  roll_No, 
  name, 
  stream,
  percentage, 
  class_rank, 
  overall_rank  )
```

I wish to query something like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM student 
 WHERE stream = 'science'
```

The expected result would be the students arranged in descending order of their rank. A requirement is that I can not specify order by clause in the query itself.

This should be achieved by an index on (stream , order by class_rank desc). Is this achievable in oracle?

Comment: The only way to guarantee result set order is with an ORDER BY clause; an index is for speeding up data retrieval where possible.

Comment: So this would appear to be a homework exercise set by a tutor who doesn't know what they are talking about.  Good luck with that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not specify an ORDER BY clause, Oracle does not guarantee the order in which rows are returned.  The requirement does not make sense.

You might get lucky and find that Oracle chooses a query plan that happens to return the rows in the order you want.  But that would be a matter of luck-- Oracle could choose a different query plan tomorrow or an Oracle version upgrade may create the results to change.  For example, folks that relied for years on the GROUP BY clause ordering the results as a side effect were distressed when a new version of Oracle added a more efficient grouping algorithm that didn't have the side effect of ordering the results.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working

```
  CREATE INDEX stream_rank_idx  ON Student (stream,class_rank desc);
```

so when ever i fire a select * from student where stream =? query the above index will be used and it will return me the desired result.

and i think its almost always safe if i am not upgrading oracle. and even after upgrade there is very low probabilty that oracle will change the way indexes are picked.

Comment: Or until you use that table in a way that Oracle decides to do a full table scan instead of using the index. This just seems like a contrived way to do something in a very unreliable manner.